# No processor claimed any of these annotations : -Werror

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I am Enabling all warnings into errors before building a build in spring boot project.
and i have to have these configurationns in the project.

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
        options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:all")
        options.compilerArgs.add("-Werror")
    }
```

but when i am building a project i am getting below error for annotations i have used.

```
No processor claimed any of these annotations: /jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank,/jakarta.validation.constraints.Email,/jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern,/jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull,/com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude,/jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty
```

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? Please provide the complete message.

Comment: it is a warning but using the above configuration I am converting the warning into an error.
so we can consider this an error

Comment: No, that means that you consider it an error.

Comment: java compiler itself considers that warnings as error and didn't allow to make a build of the project

Comment: Only because you used a configuration to force it to treat warnings as errors. That's up to you, I'm not arguing you should not do it. There can be good reasons to do it. But a warning is a warning, different from an error.

Comment: yes agree aled but it is a client requirement so I have to do it.
Please help me out if you have any solution

Answer (score 0):

The warning gets issued because you have annotations in your code, and some of these don't get processed by an annotation processor, which is pretty normal for annotations that are processed at runtime.

If you can't change the compiler configuration, which would be the reasonable thing to do you can register an Annotation Processor that processes the annotations, but does nothing.

An ugly hack, but your customer seems to essentially ask for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: This explains why this is a warning originally and not an error.